# How to properly save object that contains RealmList?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have 2 realm objects: Unit and Subunit. Unit object has a realm list of subunits. I work with single Unit object. Periodically a new Subunit object is created and added to Unit's list, and then I call copyToRealmOrUpdate on my Unit object. However, every time I call copyToRealmOrUpdate, all the Subunits that Unit contains get copied again even if they already exist in database. This causes my database to grow in size quickly.
Is there a way to save only last Subunit that was added to list every time I save Unit object? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for creating new `Subunit` instances:

```
realm.beginTransaction();

Unit unit = realm.where(Unit.class)
                 // write your condition for extracting of Unit object
                 .equalTo("id", unit_id).findFirst();

if(unit == null){
    Log.e(APP_TAG, "Unit " + unit_id + " not found");
    realm.cancelTransaction();
    return;
}

Subunit subunit = realm.createObject(Subunit.class);
// setup subunit fields

unit.getSubunits().add(subunit);

realm.commitTransaction();
```

Instead of creating `Unit` object every time your need to get this from realm by particular query and put `Subunit` instance directly to query object.

Comment: Thx, I managed to get it to work. Difference was that I was using global Unit object, and when I add Subunits to it, they don't get saved to realmlist permanently unless I call copyOrUpdate on Unit object. Now when I get Unit object using Unit unit = realm.where(Unit.class).... they get saved nicely. However, I was trying to avoid querying objects from Realm, since I'm working with only 1 Unit object at time, and the subunits are added repetitively.

Comment: Method `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` - it's also query to database, but getting object by _primary key_ via query like `realm.where(Unit.class)...` works faster. You need to store only primary key of `Unit` instance instead of object.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one `Unit`-Object and save it with `copyToRealmOrUpdate` in database.
2. When you create new `Subunit`, save him with `copyToRealmOrUpdate` in database.
3. Then you can call `Unit`-Object, that is already saved in database, and with `Unit.getSubunits().add(Subunit)` you add saved `Subunit` in database to saved `Unit` in database.

You don't need save `Unit` many times in database.